# Is a Beowulf cluster a solution for me?

Tags: server, cpu, process, cluster, beowulf

**Background**

I'm an undergrad working on an scientific experiment.
Till now I was pilot testing our one of the program  on Ubuntu 12.04 and now I need to deploy it.
The PC on which I tested the program has a Q9550 Intel processor.
The program has been written by an alumnus who was working on the experiment few years ago.

**What I know**

The programs uses lot of computing power.
*It uses all the processor cores available to it.*
It is written in Python.

**What I don't know**

I don't know much about coding.
I really don't know much about it's code.
I cannot easily tweak it.
I'm not focusing on it's technical aspects. I'm more interested in it's application

**What help I need**

The quad core processor is really really insufficient for the actual deployment of the program as it crunches a lot of data. I need to get a lot of processing cores. I do not have a big grant to buy a server with 24-core processors.

However there are many such quad core computers available in our lab all running Ubuntu and some running CentOS. Can I harness their computing power by forming a Beowulf cluster?

I'm really unaware of the code of my program, however as I mentioned earlier, it uses all the available processing cores. Would it be possible to run the program on the cluster?

If that's possible, Can someone guide me about what method of creating a Beowulf cluster would more helpful for my application?

Comment: This question is possibly on topic here - I'm not sure. However, if it is off topic (I'll see if anyone else comments) I think it might be on topic on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: If it's in python, you might be able to make use of IPython.